# Retrieving data from api (request/node.js) and trying to display it using d3

Tags: javascript, d3.js

This is the first time I've ever used `d3` or I'm trying to at least. Basically I'm getting data from a site's api and pushing it in the `xyplot` variable. I'm trying to use the `xyplot` variable to create a scatter plot but not sure how to go about it. Below is my example code that gets the data (actual api site is too long and crowds up the code example)

```
var request = require('request');
var _ = require('underscore');
var d3 = require('d3');
var api_url = "randomapisite.com"

request.get(api_url, function(err, res, body){
  var data = JSON.parse(body);
  var xyplot = [];    
  var playerData = data.resultSets[0].rowSet;

  _.each(playerData, function(playerInfo){
    xyplot.push([playerInfo[playerInfo.length - 4], playerInfo[playerInfo.length - 3]]); //x and y coords for scatter plot
  });
```

I'm not sure what to do next to make a scatter plot. I've done various things like create an svg and appending it. Most examples I've seen already have a set data laid out in their code and don't really retrieve it from an api.

Comment: What part are you stuck on in particular? There are several examples on the web that will help get you started if you don't know where to go from here - http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3887118

Comment: you would replace the call to the data loading ajax call (typically TSV) with an ajax call to your API, transforming the data that arives so that's it's in the same shape as what the example's TSV data yields, typically `[{a:"1",b:"2"},{a:"10",b:"20"}]`. if you have numbers, you can skip the code part about casting them into numbers, though it won't hurt.

Comment: Thank you both. I was having trouble understanding how to replace the call to the api instead of a TSV.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the option to get the data in JSON format? If so, could you not then use the D3 JSON call to populate your scatter chart?

For example:

```
d3.json(api_url, (error, data) =>
{
   if(error) throw error;

   // do some stuff to draw the scatter plot with the data returned
});
```